# How to access pointer of a class pointing to another pointer of a class pointing to a value

Tags: c++, pointers, indexoutofboundsexception

I’m working on project that has a high multithreading between certain classes, So I need to access a value in certain class and I want to use pointers to access it so what I do is basically described in the following:

I have 3 classes:
A.h

```
class A{
public: int myvalue;
}
```

In class A.cpp

```
class A{
A::A(){
myvalue=0;
}

function(){
myvalue++;
  }
}
```

Now I want to access this value in an intermediate class called B because I can it access directly. In class B.h

```
class B{
public: A *myptr1;
}
```

In class B.cpp

```
class B{
  B::B(){
  myptr1 = new A();
  }

  Function (){
  printf("My value is = %d \n",myptrt1->myvalue);
  }
}
```

When I run the program, my output is correct which is equal to 5. However, I need also to access this value in a third class so I use another pointer from the second class to access it.

Let's called the third class C, so in class C.h

```
class C {
public: B *myptr2;
}
```

In class C.cpp

```
class C{
  C::C(){
  myptr2 = new B();
  }

  Function (){
  printf("My value is = %d \n",myptr2->myptrt1->myvalue);
  }
}
```

When I run the program, my output was not correct. I got some values equal to zero and others are negative values so I think that the second pointer is pointing to the wrong memory location? so my question is how to access this value correctly. I try to write the code similar to my code for simplicity because the code is too big.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `*mypytr1 = ...` is wrong; remove the `*`.

Comment: @krsteeve my constructors are declared in the cpp class by default from the project files. I just added a new variable and I need to access it in this way.

Comment: @DavidRTribble this is was a typing mistake I will edit it now. Sorry about that

Comment: The code you posted is nowhere near compilable. We could fix it for you, but it's not clear whether that would help you find the bug in your actual code. You need to come up with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @redRose i think you need consider using a shared pointer instead. otherwise it is going to be a hassle keeping track of your objects.

Comment: @claptrap It is the first time I heard about shared pointer. So would you help me in how to do it?

Comment: @redRose just look it up, there are plenty of examples on the net. e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplified pseudocode that you have posted, you are accessing the `myvalue` attribute correctly and since it is zero-initialized in the `A`'s constructor and being incremented afterwards, there is no reason why its value should become negative. This seems to be rather caused by some bug (hidden within your real code) that rewrites `myvalue`'s value.

But what catches my attention more is that you have:

```
class C
{
public:
C() { bPtr = new B(); }
B* bPtr;
```

Now if the lifetime of instance of `B` contained within instance of `C` is tied to the lifetime of that instance of `C`, it seems to be reasonable for the `bPtr` to be aggregated by value ~> i.e. to be an object with automatic storage duration rather than a pointer:

```
class C
{
public:
C() { }
B b;
```

which will reduce the ugly memory management connected with working with naked pointers like these. Your code will be also much less error-prone.

Or in case you need this instance of `B` to be shared between more objects, you might also consider setting a constraint that *"instance of `C` can not exist without an instance of `B`"* (which will also cause that class `C` will not be responsible for the existence of `b`):

```
class C
{
public:
C(B& bRef) : b(bRef) { }
B& b;
```